# mySQL - How can I see which users submitted orders last month but not this month?

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, orders

I need to figure out the users who submitted orders last month but not this month. This is my current query to count total users, but how can I cross check to see who has bought this month but not the last?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(customer_user_id)
FROM customer_orders 
WHERE created_on > '2020-07-01'
```

This is my the customer orders table
[image]
this would be the expected output, a list of all the users
[image: this would be the expected output, a list of all the users]

EDIT: Additionally, I'm trying to get a report of the users who submitted orders in July but not August, with their amount total for the month, number of orders, and user cellphone #. This is the query I'm using but its not giving me the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(co.customer_user_id), SUM(co.amount), COUNT(co.order_id), s.cellphone
FROM customer_orders co
JOIN subscribers s
ON co.customer_user_id = s.user_id
WHERE co.created_on > '2020-07-01'
AND month(co.created_on) <> month(curdate());
```

This is my subscriber table, and above is my customer orders table.
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and 1) tag with db platform, 2) show table structure, 3) show sample data.  thanks

Comment: Tag the actual dbms and provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: Lol I just went down the TSQL route before seeing mysql :(

Comment: Sorry @TheMuffinMan :( if you do know SQL, I'd appreciate the help though :)

Comment: @OldProgrammer added necessary info

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 added the necessary info! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to filter the user's which are again created in current month. So,

```
-- not sure if you really need distinct
SELECT DISTINCT(c.customer_user_id)
  FROM customer_orders  c
 WHERE c.created_on > '2020-07-01'
   AND month(c.created_on) <> month(curdate());
```

Comment: Thank you! I get this error though   " Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.cd' in 'where clause'"

Comment: No worries, thank you. so this query shows the users that created orders in July but not August correct?

Comment: Yes that's right, we compare the month value of `created_on` and the current date which can be taken from `curdate()`. does it not giving expected result ?

Comment: It is, I just wanted to understand the logic behind the AND clause. Thank you again!

Comment: I just edited my question, is there a chance you could help e with that?

Comment: Yes, but i didn't get what is the new requirement ?

Comment: Just added it! :)

Comment: Normally process say we should ask new question for that but what i understood is you need `group by co.customer_user_id`  and for cellphone take use `max(cellphone)` an finally remove distinct...`SELECT co.customer_user_id, SUM(co.amount), COUNT(co.order_id), max(s.cellphone)
FROM customer_orders co
JOIN subscribers s
ON co.customer_user_id = s.user_id
WHERE co.created_on > '2020-07-01'
AND month(co.created_on) <> month(curdate())
group by co.customer_user_id;`

Comment: so I was validating the query, and when I searched some user id from the result of the query above, they show up in the august orders as well. Therefore could something be wrong with the where clause?

Comment: No I don't think so. But what you can do is for the specific user just hard code the I'd and check the date field value. Unless `month` function behaves differently it should be fine or provide sample insert as part of the question also.

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: @Strawberry  I didn't understand your point ? who said DISTINCT is a function ?

Comment: You did , when you chose to repeat the OP's error of enclosing the column in parentheses.

Comment: No what I meant by my comment is `--not sure if you really need distinct` is required or not is, if a customer is created in a month multiple times or not. i never said or mentioned word function and I would suggest not to assume things from your side. Its not an error, please run some statement in mysql with `distinct(<column_name>)`